# Accessing JSON Array "node" name with PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm using PHP,I have decoded JSON, 
for access data from json array I'm using this notation:

```
$slopes_total = $myArray['items'][0]['slopes-total'];
```

below is one part of decoded JSON

```
"items":[
        {
            "valley-run":false,
            "slopes-opened":60,
            "slopes-total":120,
            "forecast":{
                "it":{
                    "1576748703":"10:Nubi fitte, ma solo deboli piogge.",
                    "1576835103":"10:Nubi fitte, ma solo deboli piogge.",
                    "1576921503":"10:Nubi fitte, ma solo deboli piogge."
                },
                "de":{
                    "1576748703":"10:Dicke Wolken, aber nur leichter Regen.",
                    "1576835103":"10:Dicke Wolken, aber nur leichter Regen.",
                    "1576921503":"10:Dicke Wolken, aber nur leichter Regen."
                },
                "en":{
                    "1576748703":"10:Thick cloud cover but little rain only forecast.",
                    "1576835103":"10:Thick cloud cover but little rain only forecast.",
                    "1576921503":"10:Thick cloud cover but little rain only forecast."
                }
            },
```

I have no problem to access:
valley-run, slopes_opened..., the problem starts when I want to access:
forecast en (data inside this array)
in need to access each of 3 timestamp values and each of meteo descriptions.

Comment: Please show the attempts that didn't work? `$myArray['items'][0]['forecast']['it']['1576748703']` should work.

Comment: Yes, it’s working, but the problem is that '1576748703' is a variable value and i don`t know it future value , so Ii can’t access is in this way

Comment: What about "it", do you *know* that value, or do you want to *get* it?

Comment: no, JSON data is brought to us by skiresort company, we don`t have possibility to modify it. So i i need to get the timestamp value.

Comment: I meant something else: what about the *language code*... do you know the one for which you want to get the timestamps?

Comment: yes, i just need it for english 'en', data that i need is: 1: first timestamp, first meteo description, 2: second timestamp, second meteo description,  3: third timestamp, third meteo description

Comment: Note that your JSON cannot start with `"items":[`. Probably you did not provide the opening brace. Also, this is not *decoded* JSON, but the actual JSON. When you decode it, it becomes a nested PHP array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is presented in sort of JSON encoding. So first of all make sure your JSON is decoded with passing `true` as second argument to `json_decode`.

If you know the language code -- for instance "en" -- you can do:

```
foreach ($myArray['items'][0]['forecast']['en'] as $timestamp => $weather) {
    echo "$timestamp - $weather\n";
}
```

If you just need the timestamps alone, without the corresponding weather description, then:

```
$timestamps = array_keys($myArray['items'][0]['forecast']['en']);
```

If you don't know the language code, and don't care, but just want to get the timestamps from any of the language sets:

```
$timestamps = array_keys(reset($myArray['items'][0]['forecast']));
```

If you want to know which are the available languages:

```
$languages = array_keys($myArray['items'][0]['forecast']);
```